# Singleton implementation using generics

Tags: c#, generics, singleton

I did this as an exercise just to practice/improve using generics.

Independent of how useful this implementation of a Singleton is, how is my coding in terms of using generics and any other aspect of class design of code style?

```
void Main()
{
    var a = Singleton<MyClass>.Value;
    var b = Singleton<MyClass, MyClassFactory>.Value;
    var c = Singleton<MyClass>.Value;
    var d = Singleton<MyClass, MyClassFactory>.Value;
    var e = Singleton<MyOtherClass>.Value;
    var f = Singleton<MyOtherClass>.Value;
    var g = Singleton<MyOtherClass, MyOtherFactory>.Value;
    var h = Singleton<MyOtherClass, MyOtherFactory>.Value;
}

class SingletonBase
{
    protected static object Locker = new LockerObject();
}

class Singleton<T> : SingletonBase where T : new() 
{
    static T StaticT;

    public static T Value 
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                if(StaticT == null)
                {
                    StaticT = Activator.CreateInstance<Factory<T>>().Create();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Singleton<T>::Value" + typeof(T).Name + " is already created");
                }
            }
            return StaticT;
        }
    }
}

class Singleton<T, F> : SingletonBase where T : new() where F : IFactory<T>, new()
{
    static T StaticT;

    public static T Value 
    {
        get
        {
            lock (Locker)
            {
                if(StaticT == null)
                {
                    StaticT = new F().Create();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine ("Singleton<T, F>::Value" + typeof(T).Name + " is already created");
                }
            }
            return StaticT;
        }
    }
}

class LockerObject
{
    Guid myGUID;
    public LockerObject()
    {
        this.myGUID = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine ("New LockerObject " + this.myGUID.ToString());
    }
}

interface IFactory<T>
{
    T Create();
}

class Factory<T> : IFactory<T> where T : new()
{
    public T Create()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Factory<T>::Create()");  
        return new T();
    }
}

class MyClassFactory : IFactory<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass Create()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("MyClassFactory::Create()");    
        return new MyClass();
    }
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("MyClass created");
    }
}


class MyOtherClass
{
    public MyOtherClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("MyOtherClass created");
    }
}

class MyOtherFactory : IFactory<MyOtherClass>
{
    public MyOtherClass Create()
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("MyOtherFactory::Create()");    
        return new MyOtherClass();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> ```
> New LockerObject 36aa2282-d745-43ca-84d2-998a78e39d51
> Factory<T>::Create()
> MyClass created
> MyClassFactory::Create()
> MyClass created
> Singleton<T>::ValueMyClass is already created
> Singleton<T, F>::ValueMyClass is already created
> ```

Comment: a little offtopic: those are *not* singletons. As long as class `T` is required to have a public parameterless constructor, anyone can create a new instance of it. Same problem with the version using `IFactory<T>`.

Comment: understood, good point.  I was only designing it for code that makes the assumption that a DI container is able to control all object instantiation...

Comment: Does this design assure in multithreading case it creates only one object of this class?

Comment: Have a read of http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Answer (score 3):

About your locking strategy to create the singleton, I would use a double check to avoid too much locking:

```
if(x)
{
    lock(Locker)
        if(x) //again once we got the lock
            DoStuff();
} 
else 
{
    FooBar();
}
```

Like this, you will hopefully use the lock only once when you first call the instance.

Comment: +1 for more details go through http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dcl/index.html

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande I'm not sure your link is relevant. It shows that the double-locking behavior shouldn't be used with Java, but this question is about C#.

Comment: Double checked locking has visibility problems in Java. I guess @Zonko thought that the same could be true for C# too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/394898/double-checked-locking-in-net

Comment: I would stay away from this method as suggested by c# in Depth (Jon Skeet) - http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx